# Using %r, prevent 'this'

Tags: python, string

Is there any way to avoid the single-quotes around a % string?

I am trying to do this:

```
playCmd = """osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to play track %r'""" % theSong
```

that results in: ...play track 'theSong'
not: ...play track theSong
like I want.  I would just use playCmd.relpace, but because of the single-qoutes ('tell app...') before the single-quotes on theSong, I can't do this easily.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ever try `.format()`? I find its syntax much easier to work with for complex strings. For example: `Hello {person}'.format(person = 'John')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a reason why `%s` is inappropriate?  Because replacing `%r` with `%s` is the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Wow... Thanks! As I'm sure you can imagine, I'm pretty new to python.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Then you don't want `%r`; use `%s`, it will place the string in the output verbatim, without any extra quotes.

---

what's really happening is that `%s` calls `str(value)` and `%r` calls `repr(value)`.